# multiple splittings

Tags: string, powershell, split

I need a better way of doing this any ideas?

```
$strOutput = "800x600, 32 bits @ 60 Hz."

      # Initial split
$aSplitString = $strOutput.Split(",")


# Get Horizontal and Vertical Length
$aSplitString2 = $aSplitString[0].Split("x")
$strHorizontal = $aSplitString2[0]
$strVertical = $aSplitString2[1]
$aSplitString2 = $null

#Get Color Depth and Frequency
$aSplitString2 = $aSplitString[1].Split(" ")
$strColour = $aSplitString2[1]
$strFrequency = $aSplitString2[4]
```

Not a fan of using so many split functions on one string. What else could I do?

I am trying to get the individual resolution sizes, the color depth and the frequency into their on variables in the above example;

horizontal = 800
vertical = 600
color = 32
frequency = 60

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that we can pass an array of chars to the split function.
So, in one line :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> "800x600, 32 bits @ 60 Hz.".split(@("x",","," "))
800
600

32
bits
@
60
Hz.
```

Answer (score 2):

one way is:

```
$strOutput = "800x600, 32 bits @ 60 Hz."
$splitted = $strOutput -replace '\D',' ' -split '\s+'
$strHorizontal = $splitted[0] 
$strVertical = $Splitted[1]
$strColour = $splitted[2]
$strFrequency = $splitted[3]
```